# Take U.I effect every Loop on KeyDown

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm using dexExpress.XtraRichEditControl and I have this code:

```
    public int getSelectionStart { get; set; }
    public int getSelectionEnd { get; set; }

    void richEditControl1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DocumentPosition pos = richEditControl1.Document.CaretPosition;
        Paragraph par = richEditControl1.Document.GetParagraph(pos);
        DocumentPosition newPos = richEditControl1.Document.CreatePosition(par.Range.End.ToInt());

        DocumentPosition start = richEditControl1.Document.Selection.Start;
        DocumentPosition end = richEditControl1.Document.Selection.End;

        int getStartpar = richEditControl1.Document.GetParagraph(start).Index;
        getSelectionStart = getStartpar;
        int getEndpar = richEditControl1.Document.GetParagraph(end).Index;
        getSelectionEnd = getEndpar;

        if (e.Shift)
        {
            richEditControl1.Document.CaretPosition = richEditControl1.Document.CreatePosition(start.ToInt());
            DocumentPosition carPos = richEditControl1.Document.CaretPosition;
            int getParOfcarPos = richEditControl1.Document.GetParagraph(carPos).Index;

            for (int i = getParOfcarPos; i < getEndpar; i++)
            {

                NextLineCommand newLineCmd = new NextLineCommand(this.richEditControl1);
                newLineCmd.Execute();
                richEditControl1.Document.InsertText(newPos, "#");
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richEditControl1.Text =
            "aaaaa\nbbbbb\nccccc\nddddd\neeeee";
    }
```

supposedly to selectedText like:

[image]

and press ShiftKey ...

So my expected output was:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
#ccccc
#ddddd
#eeeee
```

but it was:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee###
```

I guess its because effect on UI will be executed after keydown event. So is there a way I can take effect on UI in every Loop and not just in backgroundThread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NextParagraphCommand` object instead of `NextLineCommand` and `RichEditControl.Document.CaretPosition` property for insert text:

```
NextParagraphCommand s = new NextParagraphCommand(this.richEditControl1);
s.Execute();
richEditControl1.Document.InsertText(richEditControl1.Document.CaretPosition, "#");
```

So, the result code is:

```
void richEditControl1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    DocumentPosition pos = richEditControl1.Document.CaretPosition;
    Paragraph par = richEditControl1.Document.GetParagraph(pos);
    DocumentPosition newPos = richEditControl1.Document.CreatePosition(par.Range.End.ToInt());

    DocumentPosition start = richEditControl1.Document.Selection.Start;
    DocumentPosition end = richEditControl1.Document.Selection.End;

    int getStartpar = richEditControl1.Document.GetParagraph(start).Index;
    getSelectionStart = getStartpar;
    int getEndpar = richEditControl1.Document.GetParagraph(end).Index;
    getSelectionEnd = getEndpar;

    if (e.Shift)
    {
        richEditControl1.Document.CaretPosition = richEditControl1.Document.CreatePosition(start.ToInt());
        DocumentPosition carPos = richEditControl1.Document.CaretPosition;
        int getParOfcarPos = richEditControl1.Document.GetParagraph(carPos).Index;

        for (int i = getParOfcarPos; i < getEndpar; i++)
        {

            NextParagraphCommand s = new NextParagraphCommand(this.richEditControl1);
            s.Execute();
            richEditControl1.Document.InsertText(richEditControl1.Document.CaretPosition, "#");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still same result will happen for that . @nempoBu4

Comment: @Elegiac Result will not be the same. I checked it by myself. Did you tried this?

Comment: yes id tried it did you copy the method on keydown? @nempoBu4
or copy my codes above?

Comment: @Elegiac I copied the whole method and just changed a few lines. I have updated answer with your method.